# Cache-aligned stack variables

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

Using new C++11 alignment tools I wanted to make sure that a set of temporary (stack) variables will lie in one cache line. My first naive attempt was as follows:

```
int main() {
    alignas(64) int a; // 0x7fffc58aac80, properly aligned at 64
    int b; // 0x7fffc58aac7c
    int c; // 0x7fffc58aac78
    return 0;
}
```

Stupid me! Stack doesn't allocate the variables this way, thus `a` will be on different cache line than `b` and `c`.

Does this mean that the *only way to properly align several variables is through an aggregate*?

```
struct alignas(64) Abc {
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
};

int main() {
   Abc foo;
   // x 0x7fff40c2d3c0 (aligned at 64)
   // y 0x7fff40c2d3c4
   // z 0x7fff40c2d3c8   
   return 0;
}
```

Compiler: Clang 3.2

Comment: Do you really think that having all of these variables in the same cache line is going to improve performance? Odds are pretty good that the stack is in the cache.

Comment: It *could* have an impact if these variables need to be shared among multiple cores, such that whichever core wants to write to these, needs to use all three variables at a time. If they all lie in the same cache line and accesses to these variable are rare, the coherency traffic would be reduced. However there's no guarantee that the line can be invalidated between reading two variables in the same line.

Comment: Modern compiles don't even keep stack variables in a fixed location (unless you take their address, of course). So if `a` and `b` shared a cache line, after a write to either one that can change. (This is typical for Static Single Assignment optimalization)

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure, might be (especially as every other method is using stack). But what in a case where you have quite large lookup-like table (close to 64B) on which you will operate and you don't want to incur additional cache reads?

Comment: @RedXIII: Assuming a 64-byte cache line size, let's say that half of it goes in one line and half in another. Well, you already have the first half in the cache, since you've almost certainly used other memory in that cache line before now (just the return address from the function is enough). So you'll only ever need to fetch the second half; that's one cache line read. If the table happens to land on a cache line boundary like you want, it's still just one cache line read. So you get one line read *regardless* of where it lands.

Answer (score 4):

To properly align several variables you must use an aggregate, because the layout for automatic variables is not defined.  I can't find anything in the C++11 standard that says variables with automatic storage have to be allocated on the stack in the same order they are defined.  Section 5.9 of the standard insists that only a few kinds of pointer comparisons are defined, and comparisons between variables with automatic storage is not among those listed as defined.